# what is the id_by_element in 'Select(driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_element')) in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use selenium on [this](http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/) page, to type '22663' into the box that says 'search by plant-based food' and then click 'food-disease association'; and then click submit on the bottom of the page (and then, as a bigger picture, to then click 'plant-disease associations' on the next page, and then export the plant-disease table).

I am following [these](https://www.techbeamers.com/navigation/) instructions, and I wrote this code:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


url = 'http://147.8.185.62/services/NutriChem-2.0/'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/Users/kela/Desktop/scripts/scraping/geckodriver')
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_id("input_food_name")
element.send_keys("22663")

#click food-disease association
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='food_search_section']")
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
```

The next two lines are where I have the issue:

```
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('food_input'))
element.select_by_value('food_disease')
```

I am getting the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <td>
```

My issue is that I'm not understanding, on [this](https://www.techbeamers.com/navigation/) page, to what is the 'id_of_element' referring to in my case (to be able to select food-disease associations in the 'search by plant-based food' section); so for example what do i replace the X with in the following line of code, to then click submit, and go on to the next page:

```
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('X'))
element.select_by_value('X')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `#food_input` alone gives you a table cell `<td>`, you need to select the `<select>` element under it

[image]

Change

```
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('food_input'))
```

into

```
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#food_input select'))
```

or just

```
element = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[name=food_search_section]'))
```

to target the `<select>` element.